# flink type system- registerType for the subtype

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/serialization/types_serialization/#most-frequent-issues

It says:

> Registering subtypes: If the function signatures describe only the
> supertypes, but they actually use subtypes of those during execution,
> it may increase performance a lot to make Flink aware of these
> subtypes. For that, call .registerType(clazz) on the
> StreamExecutionEnvironment or ExecutionEnvironment for each subtype.

Is there test case or code example to demonstrate the usage of this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
DataStream<Msg> test = stream.map(x -> (x < 10) ? new Msg1() : new Msg2());
```

You should register these subtypes:

```java
env.registerType(Msg1.class);
env.registerType(Msg2.class);
```

The `PojoSerializer` tags each instance with either the subclass' full name,
a subclass tag when registered (as above), or serializes the target type directly (no tag).
As such, type registration is not needed if you always use the
given type directly and never serialize any subclass instances. But when they will be serialized, the registering the subclasses produces tags that are more compact (and more efficient) than the full subclass names.